# PSSH box missing when generating encrypted files using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, exoplayer

I am trying to play from local storage an encrypted video using ExoPlayer. The command used to encrypt the video using FFMPEG is as follows:

`-i /storage/emulated/0/Download/20210125_193031.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -c:v libx264 -encryption_scheme cenc-aes-ctr -encryption_key b42ca3172ee4e69bf51848a59db9cd13 -encryption_kid 09e367028f33436ca5dd60ffe6671e70 /storage/emulated/0/Download/out_enc.mp4`  - the file is playable using openkey and `ffplay`, but it won't play on ExoPlayer

The main issue seems the PSSH box seems to be missing when generating the encrypted file

Is there a command option in order to add the PSSH box inside the mp4 file? I think that's why the ExoPlayer is unable to play the file.

Comment: It seems ExoPlayer is reading `only` PSSH box when MP4 is fragmented. Even is present there by executing ffmpeg command, it is not read in simple MP4 files. HLS/DASH needed. https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/8532#issuecomment-771811707

Comment: I used mp4box, that is including pssh box