# How to play local saved AES encrypted file in Exoplayer andorid

Tags: android, encryption, exoplayer

How can I play large AES encrypted file in exoplayer, I did it in two steps first decrypt file with new name and then play newly created video. But this is not an smooth behavior and it's taking 1-2 min if file size is more than 1 GB.

Please help me and thank you in advance.

Comment: This may help avoid the two steps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62678769/334402

Comment: It's not working and this in Kotlin, I'm looking in java.