# media3.Exoplayer not playing encrypted videos

Tags: android, encryption, video, aes, exoplayer

I'm trying to play a encrypted video that is stored locally on my mobile phone.
The video is encrypted using AES ecnryption, however when I try to play the video, it keeps calling open() from my EncryptedDataSource indefinitely.

I already tried using the solution from [Android + exoplayer: play AES encrypted videos, locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62565879/android-exoplayer-play-aes-encrypted-videos-locally), but it gives me the same result, "infinite loop". From this solution I used the return value for the open(), which is "dataspec.length".

I also tried the implementation from FileDataSource which is

```
      bytesRemaining =
          dataSpec.length == C.LENGTH_UNSET ? file.length() - dataSpec.position : dataSpec.length;
```

but I also got the same result.

Below you can see my code, as well as the logs I get when I click on the Play button on the player.

```
public class UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment extends Fragment {
.
.
.


    @OptIn(markerClass = UnstableApi.class)
    private void playEncryptedVideo() {
        byte[] key = {-26, -118, 28, 83, 31, 106, 93, -40, -87, 7, -16, -54, -27, 80, 75, 95};
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key, CryptoUtils.AES);

        byte[] iv = {30, -92, -115, 38, -123, 124, 110, -86, -28, 110, 33, 101, 36, -37, 66, -54};

        ExoPlayer player = new ExoPlayer.Builder(this.getContext()).build();
        this.playerView.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory encryptedDataSourceFactory = new EncryptedDataSourceFactory(iv, secretKeySpec);

        try {
            Path pathImagesCacheFolder = CacheManager.INSTANCE.imagesCacheFolder();
            Path pathImage = pathImagesCacheFolder.resolve("test_video_cbc_result_encrypted.mp4");

            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(pathImage.toFile());
            MediaItem mediaItem = new MediaItem.Builder().setUri(uri).build();

            MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(encryptedDataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(mediaItem);
            player.setMediaSource(videoSource);
            player.play();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }



    public static class EncryptedDataSourceFactory implements DataSource.Factory {
        private byte[] iv;
        private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;

        public EncryptedDataSourceFactory(byte[] iv, SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec) {
            this.iv = iv;
            this.secretKeySpec = secretKeySpec;
        }

        @Override
        @UnstableApi
        public DataSource createDataSource() {
            return new EncryptedDataSource(this.iv, this.secretKeySpec);
        }
    }




    @UnstableApi
    public static class EncryptedDataSource implements DataSource {
        private byte[] iv;
        private SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec;

        public EncryptedDataSource(byte[] iv, SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec) {
            this.iv = iv;
            this.secretKeySpec = secretKeySpec;
        }

        private CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = null;
        private Uri uri;

        public void addTransferListener(TransferListener transferListener) {}

        public long open(DataSpec dataSpec) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[" + dataSpec.length + "], dataSpec.position[" + dataSpec.position + "]");

            this.uri = dataSpec.uri;
            try {
                File file = new File(uri.getPath());
                InputStream fileInputStream = Files.newInputStream(file.toPath(), StandardOpenOption.READ);

                Cipher cipher = CryptoUtils.newAES_CBC_PKCS5_Instance();
                cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(this.iv));
                this.cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);

            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "Error", e);

            }

            return dataSpec.length;
        }

        @Override
        public int read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int readLength) throws IOException {
            int result = 0;

            if (readLength == 0) {
                result = 0;
            } else {
                result = this.cipherInputStream.read(buffer, offset, readLength);
            }

            return result;
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public Uri getUri() {
            return uri;
        }

        public void close() throws IOException {
            this.cipherInputStream.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Logs

```
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401066037080]
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401138141760]
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401210246440]
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401282351120]
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401354455800]
I/com.example.fragment.viewfragment.UserFilesMediaVideoViewFragment: Opening Encrypted Data Source. dataSpec.length[-1], dataSpec.position[1401426560480]
..
.
.
```

Does anybody have any idea what I'm doing wrong?