Playing encrypted Videos using ExoPlayer
I'm developing a video app where videos are downloaded from the internet then encrypted so that only the user of the app can watch them but can't copy them even if he is using a rooted phone.
I used this class to encrypt and decrypt the videos:
class CryptoManager {

    // loading keystore

    private val keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore").apply {
        load(null)
    }

    private val encryptCipher
        get() = Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
            init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, getKey())
        }

     fun getDecryptCipherForIv(iv: ByteArray): Cipher {
        return Cipher.getInstance(TRANSFORMATION).apply {
            init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, getKey(), IvParameterSpec(iv))
        }
    }

     fun getKey(): SecretKey {
        val existingKey = keyStore.getEntry(ALIAS, null) as? KeyStore.SecretKeyEntry
        return existingKey?.secretKey ?: createKey()
    }

    private fun createKey(): SecretKey {
        return KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM).apply {
            init(
                KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(
                    ALIAS,
                    KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT
                )
                    .setKeySize(KEY_SIZE * 8) // key size in bits
                    .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                    .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                    .setUserAuthenticationRequired(false)
                    .setRandomizedEncryptionRequired(true)
                    .build()
            )
        }.generateKey()
    }

    fun encrypt(inputStream: InputStream, outputStream: OutputStream) {
        val cipher = encryptCipher
        val iv = cipher.iv
        outputStream.use {
            it.write(iv)
            // write the payload in chunks to make sure to support larger data amounts (this would otherwise fail silently and result in corrupted data being read back)
            ////////////////////////////////////

            val buffer = ByteArray(CHUNK_SIZE)
            while (inputStream.available() > CHUNK_SIZE) {
                inputStream.read(buffer)
                val ciphertextChunk = cipher.update(buffer)
                it.write(ciphertextChunk)
            }
            // the last chunk must be written using doFinal() because this takes the padding into account
            val remainingBytes = inputStream.readBytes()
            val lastChunk = cipher.doFinal(remainingBytes)
            it.write(lastChunk)
            //////////////////////////////////
        }
    }

    fun decrypt(inputStream: InputStream): ByteArrayOutputStream{
        return inputStream.use {
            val iv = ByteArray(KEY_SIZE)
            it.read(iv)
            val cipher = getDecryptCipherForIv(iv)
            val outputStream = ByteArrayOutputStream()

            // read the payload in chunks to make sure to support larger data amounts (this would otherwise fail silently and result in corrupted data being read back)
            ////////////////////////////////////
            val buffer = ByteArray(CHUNK_SIZE)
            while (inputStream.available() > CHUNK_SIZE) {
                inputStream.read(buffer)
                val ciphertextChunk = cipher.update(buffer)
                outputStream.write(ciphertextChunk)
            }
            // the last chunk must be read using doFinal() because this takes the padding into account
            val remainingBytes = inputStream.readBytes()
            val lastChunk = cipher.doFinal(remainingBytes)
            outputStream.write(lastChunk)
            //////////////////////////////////

            outputStream
        }
    }

    companion object {
        private const val CHUNK_SIZE = 1024 * 16 // bytes
         const val KEY_SIZE = 16 // bytes
        private const val ALIAS = "my_alias"
         const val ALGORITHM = KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_AES
        private const val BLOCK_MODE = KeyProperties.BLOCK_MODE_CBC
        private const val PADDING = KeyProperties.ENCRYPTION_PADDING_NONE
         const val TRANSFORMATION = "$ALGORITHM/$BLOCK_MODE/$PADDING"
    }

}

When opening (decrypt then play) large videos (100MB+) it takes any phone too much time to load the video since it's decryption returns a ByteArray which sits in the memory. sometime it even threw OutOfMemoryexception.
I spent days searching till I found this solution: Android + exoplayer: play AES encrypted videos, locally
I applied the solution and even tried an updated on that was posted by the same developer in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77373582/8555515
here is my implementation:
    @UnstableApi
    class EncryptedDataSourceFactory(
        private val filePath: String,
        private val decryptionCipher: Cipher
    ) : DataSource.Factory {
        override fun createDataSource(): DataSource {
            return EncryptedDataSource(filePath, decryptionCipher)
        }
    }

    @UnstableApi
    class EncryptedDataSource(
        private val filePath: String,
        private val decryptionCipher: Cipher
    ) : DataSource {

        private var inputStream: InputStream? = null

        override fun open(dataSpec: DataSpec): Long {

            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "Opening file: $filePath")
            inputStream = FileInputStream(filePath)

            Assertions.checkNotNull(inputStream, "Failed to open InputStream")

            val fileLength = File(filePath).length()
            val length = if (dataSpec.length == C.LENGTH_UNSET.toLong()) {
                fileLength - dataSpec.position
            } else {
                dataSpec.length
            }

            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "DataSpec position: ${dataSpec.position}, length: $length")


            // Skip to the position specified by ExoPlayer
            val skipped = inputStream?.skip(dataSpec.position) ?: 0
            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "Skipped bytes: $skipped")

            return length
        }

        override fun read(buffer: ByteArray, offset: Int, readLength: Int): Int {

            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "Entering read method")

            // Read encrypted data from the file
            val encryptedData = ByteArray(readLength)
            val bytesRead =
                inputStream?.read(encryptedData, 0, readLength) ?: return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
            if (bytesRead == -1) {
                Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "End of input stream")
                return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
            }
            // Decrypt the data
            val decryptedData = decryptionCipher.update(encryptedData, 0, bytesRead)
            Assertions.checkNotNull(decryptedData, "Cipher update returned null")

            if (decryptedData == null) {
                Log.e("EncryptedDataSource", "Decryption returned null")
                return C.RESULT_END_OF_INPUT
            }

            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "Decrypted ${decryptedData.size} bytes")
            // Copy decrypted data into the buffer
            System.arraycopy(decryptedData, 0, buffer, offset, decryptedData.size)
            return decryptedData.size
        }

        override fun addTransferListener(transferListener: TransferListener) {

        }

        override fun close() {

            Log.d("EncryptedDataSource", "Closing InputStream")
            inputStream?.close()
            inputStream = null
        }

        override fun getUri(): Uri? = null
    }
}


Both of them had the same problem. The Implementation of the Custom datasource class the open() function is never called
why is it never called, and is there a better solution de decrypt and play videos on an android phone
